# excel paste value in the last empty row

Tags: excel, vba

This formula:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((COUNTIF(A$54:A54,F$2:F$52)=0)*(F$2:F$52<>"")),F$2:F$52),"")
```

copy values range F2:F52 in range A54:A77
Is it possible that they are pasted into the first empty cell?
I hope I explained myself
max

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question - what are you trying to do?

Comment: I hope to explain myself.
I add an example value to F10 and this value is pasted with the formula in the A54 range
I add an example value to F20 and this value is pasted with the formula in the range A55
The formula must always paste the values into the first empty cell of the A55: A77 range

Comment: You can't alter other cells values through a formula in another cell. Use VBA for this

Comment: help for a macro

Answer (score 0):

I hope to explain myself.
I add an example value to F10 and this value is pasted with the formula in the A54 range I add an example value to F20 and this value is pasted with the formula in the range A55 The formula must always paste the values into the first empty cell of the A55:A77 range